# Latex macro in bookdown theorem

Tags: bookdown

I am trying to use some latex macro in a bookdown project (which is an amazing technology!).

I would like to write in the text (and in the theorem environment) symbols like |x>, for which in normal latex document I would get using the package braket. In practice, in a latex file I would write

```
\usepackage{braket}
```

I don't understand why, but adding in the preamble \usepackage{braket} does not work, as $\ket{x}$ does not get rendered correctly in the text.

To circumvent this issue I got the idea of adding some macros, at the beginning of the markdown file.

```
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\bra{\langle}{\rvert}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\ket{\lvert}{\rangle} 
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\braket[2]{\langle}{\rangle}{#1 \delimsize\vert #2}
```

Unfortunately, it does not solve the issue. In both cases, I get the following error:

```
[WARNING] Could not convert TeX math '\ket{\psi}', rendering as TeX:
  \ket{\psi}
      ^
  unexpected "{"
  expecting "%", "\\label", "\\nonumber" or whitespace
```

Any idea on how to solve this problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You have to put the LaTeX code into a separate .tex file, which you then provide to the YAML option `includes`.

Example:

**add_packages.tex**

`\usepackage{braket}`

**index.Rmd**

```
--- 
output:
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    includes:
      in_header: add_packages.tex
documentclass: book
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
---

# Let's test `braket`

$$\bra{\Psi}\ket{\Psi}$$
```

[image]

See Yihui's [documentation](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/yaml-options.html) of the bookdown package for more.

Comment: Or if you don't prefer including an external .tex file, you may use the option `extra_dependencies`: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/latex-extra.html

Comment: Can this inclusion be done for an html output as well? I tried to ad this whith the `bookdown::gitbook:` section but it doesn't seem to parse the macros defined in the included file.

Comment: I don't think there is an easy fix because HTML relies on mathjax which is different from latex.